# Querying data sends back the name of my database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

When i try to query data from my DB and put it in to a sentence. It copies the DB name and table. It doesn't show the data that in the DB.

Its a local SQL file DB. The Table of the DB is called Word.
inside are two words "Hello" and "World". I'm  trying to make the starter sentence Hello World.

```
namespace OllaWereldApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (SentencesEntities context = new SentencesEntities())
            {
                //context.Words.Add(new Word { Name = "Hello" });
                //context.Words.Add(new Word { Name = "Wereld" });
                //context.SaveChanges();

                Word word = context.Words.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Id == 1);
                Word wereld = context.Words.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Name == "Wereld");
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", word, wereld);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

actual output:
`OllaWereldApp.Word OllaWereldApp.Word`

Expacted output:
`Hello Wereld`

ps. yea its an english first word and a Dutch second one. (this is correctly with the DB).

Comment: What is `Word`? Does it have a `.Value` property? Your `WriteLine()` function is calling `word.ToString()` implicitly which retrurns the variable type but I think you're after the actual value so try `word.Value`

Comment: You sir, seem to be correct!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should override the `ToString()` method in the `Word` class in order to use the objects like this in the `WriteLine` or call the `Name` getter directly like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", word.Name, wereld.Name);
```

Comment: Thank you. that is correct. So my word & wereld are only navigations to the DB table, but it didnt store the data?

Comment: The data is contained within the `word` and `whereld` objects. You need to call the `Name` property getter in order to retrieve that data from the object. In other words, what you are getting from the DB are the two `Word` objects and the data sits within them in the `Name` property that you defined.

Comment: I rarely find a good enough reason to override `.ToString()` othan than for some  debugging purposes. In OP's case the expected value can be accessed via an existing `.Value` property so there's no need to override `.ToString()`.

Comment: I agree with user12345 about ToString() usage. @jrikken12 if you find the answer helped to resolve your issue please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Marked :), quiet new to this as you can tell.